# changing color of text color with input slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have html code that is being generated via PHP. The PHP assigns a class to a specific  depending on whether or not it is below a given threshold. The range can be anywhere from 0-5, including decimal numbers. I would like to be able to use a slider to change the threshold dynamically. This means that I would like to be able to change the color of the div's as I increase, or decrease, the threshold via the slider. I have set up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kiriek/3crx6dzs/) that shows you a simple example of what I mean. I have html code commented out that shows you what the result should be at a couple different thresholds. I am a beginner with JQuery/JS so I do not know where to start. I tried to change the value in the textbox as you move the slider, but I could not even get that to work.

```
<br/>
<!--Input slider to change the threshold
     and the color of the numbers -->
<form action="slider.html" style="float:right;">
    <input id="slider1" type="range" value="2" min="0" max="5" step="1" onchange="printValue('slider1','rangeValue1')"/>
    <input id="rangeValue1" type="text" size="2"/>
</form>

<!--This is what it should look like at a threshold of 2 -->
<div class = "wrapped" >
    <div class = "post" > This is an example of a post </div>
    <div class = "bully"> 2.50 </div>
</div>
<div class = "wrapped" >
    <div class = "post" > This is an example of a second post </div>
    <div class = "normal"> 1.50 </div>
</div>

<!-- This is what it should look like at a threshold of 3
<div class = "wrapped" >
    <div class = "post" > This is an example of a post </div>
    <div class = "normal"> 2.50 </div>
</div>
<div class = "wrapped" >
    <div class = "post" > This is an example of a second post </div>
    <div class = "normal"> 1.50 </div>
</div> -->

<!-- This is what it should look like at a threshold of 1
<div class = "wrapped" >
    <div class = "post" > This is an example of a post </div>
    <div class = "bully"> 2.50 </div>
</div>
<div class = "wrapped" >
    <div class = "post" > This is an example of a second post </div>
    <div class = "bully"> 1.50 </div>
</div> -->
```

This is the HTML code for my example. The CSS and JQuery code is included on the JSFiddle. Thanks in advance for all of your help!

Kirie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/5mv3snwn/) is a working example that shows you how to use jQuery to update the textbox and the text depending on the value of the slider.

```
//Initialize the value in the textbox
$(document).ready(function() {
    updateSliderValue($('#slider1').val());

    $('#slider1').change(function() {
        updateSliderValue($(this).val());
    });
});

function updateSliderValue(newValue) {    
   $('#rangeValue1').val(newValue);
   $('.wrapped .value').html(newValue);

   if (newValue > 2) {
      $('.wrapped .value').removeClass('normal').addClass('bully');
   } else {
      $('.wrapped .value').removeClass('bully').addClass('normal');
}
```

**EDIT:**

I've updated the jsFiddle to do what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/xuocsch9/1/

Comment: Thanks! I do not want the number in the div to change though. I just want the color to change. So it would look something like if(newValue > div.val) I think? But div's cannot have values. So I would need another element that can hold some value, right?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to bind a onchange event to your slider.

```
$("#slider1").change(function(){
    printValue('slider1', 'rangeValue1');    
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3crx6dzs/4/) using jQuery to add a new onchange on the slider so the value gets updated.